# PROCHOT flag set at 82 degrees

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature

[image: HWiNFO64 screenshot]

I'm encountering a problem with my gaming laptop where the PROCHOT flag is triggered at a low package temperature, as visible in the screenshot above. My laptop is an Alienware 17 R4 featuring an Intel i7-7820HK processor and a NVIDIA GTX 1070 GPU.

From what I understand, the flag is normally set at 105 degrees, but manufacturers are allowed to deviate from that by 15 degrees, making a minimum of 90 degrees. As my temperature is still quite far below that, I find it weird that the flag is set.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening, and whether or not it means a my laptop has a defect?

Comment: You left the column headers off your picture. I can't tell what that info is supposed to be saying.

Comment: My bad. From left to right, it's the current, min, max and average values. The 3rd column from the left is the relevant one.

Comment: I still don't understand your figures. Usually the ProcHot value is *distance to prochot*, so you take the current CPU temp, add dist to prochot & the 2 added give you the actual max temperature. Mine, for instance right now shows CPU 52, ProcHot 44, giving a max of 96.

Comment: That value is displayed below the core temperature, in the `Core #X distance to max`. The PROCHOT flag is should only be triggered when the CPU "gets too hot", which isn't the case.